# NEON SSUBL instruction has wrong result? 127-220 = 0x00a3(should be 0xffa3)

Tags: arm, neon, arm64, armasm

I have a problem when using `ssubl` instruction in A64 instruction set.

I just want to subtract a constant value from an 8-byte SIMD vector. As the result might include a negative number, I use `ssubl` to extend the data range and do the signed subtraction.

Here is my code:

```
mov w4, #127    // set a const
mov w5, #220    // set another const

dup v1.16b, w4  // move the const to a vector
dup v2.16b, w5  // move the const to a vector

ssubl v3.8h, v1.8b, v2.8b // long type vector subtraction, 127-220
```

I checked the result in the vector register v1, v2 and v3:

- v1: all 0x7f (decimal 127)
- v2: all 0xdc (decimal 220)
- v3: all 0x00a3 (decimal 163), **WRONG**

*[127 - 220 = -93 (0xffa3), **CORRECT**]*

I think the value in v3 should be 0xff5d, as it's a negative number. But why it's not?

---

Actually, after few tests, I found this problem is not related to the value in `w5`, no matter it's 220 or 230 or other value. **As long as the value in `w4` is less or equal to 127, the subtraction result is not correct.**

So, if we use the same code, but change w4 value to 128 or larger:

```
mov w4, #128    // set a const
mov w5, #220    // set another const

dup v1.16b, w4  // move the const to a vector
dup v2.16b, w5  // move the const to a vector

ssubl v3.8h, v1.8b, v2.8b // long type vector subtraction, 128-220
```

The results now are:

- v1: all 0x80 (decimal 128)
- v2: all 0xdc (decimal 220)
- v3: all 0xffa4 (decimal -92), **CORRECT**

*[128 - 220 = -92 (0xffa4), **CORRECT**]*

Now the results are correct, and I also tried using 150, 250 in `w5`, all results are correct. **The problem is only related to the value in `w4`.**

Is there anyone can explain that?

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to consider what an eight-bit integer that you assign `220` to will represent when interpreted as *signed* by `ssubl`.

Comment: @EOF: it's not about 220. I tried 150, 250 for `w5`. The result is only related to the value in `w4`

Comment: You probably want `usubl` when the _input_ operands are unsigned.  The result of a subtraction is both signed and unsigned and it's your choice how to interpret it, but because the input operands must be either zero-extended or sign-extended, it's important to specify that.

Comment: `127 - (-36) == 163` - seems legit. You're doing a subtraction of signed _byte_ operands (yielding a signed halfword result) with that `ssubl`, remember. What were you expecting the signed byte representation of 220 to be?

Comment: @sh1: Yes, I tried `usubl`, which get correct result. I think yes, the `usubl` and `ssubl` only care about if the operands are signed/unsigned

Comment: @Notlikethat: Yes, the 220 cannot be represented by a signed _byte_. `usubl` corrects this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Posted solution on behalf of the OP)*.

Use `usubl` rather than `ssubl` to do the subtraction.

It seems like the `usubl` and `ssubl` only care about if the **operands** are signed/unsigned.